RASA [3.6.20] NLU model "training successfully" immediately but only returning 'null'
I am trying to upgrade from RASA 2 to RASA 3, and am having a problem I don’t understand. I’m trying to train an NLU model, and when I run the ‘rasa train’ command I get terminal output indicating that my model has trained successfully–but the epoch bar never displays, and training seems to complete immediately. When I open the model using ‘rasa shell’, it returns null with 0 confidence for any input.
Asked at the RASA forums, but haven't gotten any responses. Any ideas what could be causing this issue? Thanks.
I’m running RASA version 3.6.20 with spaCy version 3.7.6 in a python 3.9 virtual environment. Here’s my config file:
version: “3.1” 
recipe: “default.v1” 
language: en 
pipeline:
name: SpacyNLP 
model: en_core_web_sm
name: SpacyTokenizer
name: SpacyFeaturizer
name: SpacyEntityExtractor
name: RegexFeaturizer 
analyzer: char_wb 
min_ngram: 1 
max_ngram: 4
name: DIETClassifier 
epochs: 100 
constrain_similarities: true
name: EntitySynonymMapper 
policies:
name: MemoizationPolicy 
assistant_id: 20240813-193423-felt-modal

here is the last part of the terminal output from training, note no epoch bar:
2024-08-29 17:45:41 INFO rasa.nlu.utils.spacy_utils - Trying to load SpaCy model with name ‘en_core_web_sm’. 
2024-08-29 17:45:42 INFO rasa.nlu.utils.spacy_utils - Trying to load SpaCy model with name ‘en_core_web_sm’. 
2024-08-29 17:45:43 INFO rasa.engine.training.hooks - Starting to train component ‘RegexFeaturizer’. 
2024-08-29 17:45:43 INFO rasa.engine.training.hooks - Finished training component ‘RegexFeaturizer’. 
2024-08-29 17:45:43 INFO rasa.engine.training.hooks - Starting to train component ‘DIETClassifier’. 
2024-08-29 17:45:43 INFO rasa.engine.training.hooks - Finished training component ‘DIETClassifier’. 
2024-08-29 17:45:43 INFO rasa.engine.training.hooks - Starting to train component ‘EntitySynonymMapper’. 
2024-08-29 17:45:43 INFO rasa.engine.training.hooks - Finished training component ‘EntitySynonymMapper’. 
Your Rasa model is trained and saved at ‘models/nlu-20240829-174541-heartless-bayou.tar.gz’. 
Rasa model training completed successfully.

Here’s the terminal output from running ‘rasa shell’ with a sample input:
2024-08-29 18:05:26 INFO rasa.core.processor - Loading model models/nlu-20240829-        174541-heartless-bayou.tar.gz… 
2024-08-29 18:05:26 INFO rasa.nlu.utils.spacy_utils - Trying to load SpaCy model with name ‘en_core_web_sm’. 
2024-08-29 18:05:28 INFO rasa.nlu.utils.spacy_utils - Trying to load SpaCy model with name ‘en_core_web_sm’. 
NLU model loaded. Type a message and press enter to parse it. 
Next message: Hello, this is a test message. 
{ “text”: “Hello, this is a test message.”, 
“intent”: { “name”: null, “confidence”: 0.0 }, 
“entities”: , 
“text_tokens”: [ [ 0, 5 ], [ 5, 6 ], [ 7, 11 ], [ 12, 14 ], [ 15, 16 ], [ 17, 21 ], [ 22, 29 ], [ 29, 30 ] ], 
“intent_ranking”:  } 
Next message:

Additionally, the models produced vary in size considerably. Here are one of the 'null' response only RASA 3 models, another RASA 3 model that trained for 3 hours and only produces very low confidence results, and a RASA 2 model I trained today (in 20 minutes) for size comparison purposes.First number (e.g., 2456, is filesize). The RASA 2 model is almost twice the size of the RASA 3 model that sort of works, and many times larger than the only RASA 3 models I've been able to create since then.
RASA 3, 'null' only: 2456 Aug 30 14:20 nlu-20240830-142056-poky-turret.tar.gz
RASA 3, 3+ hour train:19923109 Aug 13 16:08 nlu-20240730-180020-hot-event.tar.gz
RASA 2: 37456829 Sep 3 18:24 nlu-20240903-182449.tar.gz


Since the vm I am working on does not have a GPU allocated to it, I thought that downloading the CPU-only version of tensorflow might solve my problem. But after uninstalling the default version, installing tensorflow-cpu, and linking the two so that rasa will recognize the latter as the former, the behavior when training is the same: it still trains immediately and produces a junk model.

I have downgraded to RASA 3.2.13 in a fresh python 3.9.x virtual environment hoping that might address the issue, but I am still seeing the same issue with the model training immediately and not displaying the epoch bar.
